# Can i get the mail of a message sender or receiver using Gmail API in PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, gmail

i'm trying to build a webmail to help my team checking their mails faster. But somehow i don't get the full response when i ask for the full raw message or the header, it cuts the text between < and >.

The API Explorer returns (response reduce to what's interesting) :

`"\"Google Download Your Data\" \u003cnoreply@google.com\u003e"`

(\u003c is <)

when i get (response reduce to what's interesting) :

`"Google Download Your Data"`

Code :

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
$client->setAuthConfig(PATH_TO_CRED);
$client->setSubject(MAIL);

$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me');
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    $mail = $service->users_messages->get('me', $message->getId());
    foreach ($mail->getPayload()->getHeaders() as $header) {
        if ($header->getName() == 'From') {
            echo $header->getValue();
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/encode_decode/ to decode the RAW message and i got the mail, but can't get to get the same response with PHP.

Comment: It was the most simple thing to say, my boss want a tool to process mails faster and to have a share tool instead of using the same gmail account that got critical informations

Answer (score 0):

Just need to declare the header application/json.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```